# Getting a particular string from a line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a script extract all the services from /etc/init.d folder. I will extract the details to a file. Then i will search for a string and extract the service which i require. But this is not working for me. Can someone help me in this?

My Code:

```
import re, ConfigParser, paramiko, xlwt, collections, os

def get_status():
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read('config.cfg')
    component = []
    for section in sorted(config.sections(), key=str.lower):
        components = dict() #start with empty dictionary for each section
        if not config.has_option(section, 'server.user_name'):
            continue
        env.user = config.get(section, 'server.user_name')
        env.password = config.get(section, 'server.password')
        host = config.get(section, 'server.ip')
        print "Trying to connect to {} server.....".format(section)

        with settings(hide('warnings', 'running', 'stdout', 'stderr'),warn_only=True, host_string=host):
            try:
                files = run('ls -ltr /etc/init.d/')
                with open(section + "_tmp"+".txt", "w") as fo:
                    fo.write(files)
                with open(section + "_tmp"+".txt", 'rb') as fo:
                    strings = ("->")
                    for line in fo:
                        if strings in line:
                            m = re.match('.* nds_([-_a-z0-9]+) ', line)
                            if m:
                                component = m.group(1).strip('nds_')
                                print component
            except Exception as e:
                print e
```

My /etc/init.d shows like this

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 15407 Jan 28  2013 libvirt-guests
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  9964 Apr  9  2014 jexec
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    36 Apr  9  2014 nds_watchdog -> /opt/nds/watchdog/utils/nds_watchdog
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    28 Apr  9  2014 nds_snmp -> /opt/nds/snmp/utils/nds_snmp
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    36 Apr  9  2014 nds_ndsagent -> /opt/nds/ndsagent/utils/nds_ndsagent
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    28 Apr  9  2014 nds_mama -> /opt/nds/mama/utils/nds_mama
```

I require the complete string which starts with 'nds_'. For eg: in this case, i require nds_watchdog, nds_snmp, nds_ndsagent, nds_mama. I am sure there should be better solutions to extract using re. Can someone help me in this?

The output showing is:

```
Trying to connect to Astro server.....
Connected to Astro server
watchdog
mp
agent
```

Comment: Could you include details on how exactly this isn't working for you? It isn't immediately clear to me.

Comment: @BlackVegetable .. I have added the current output in the main section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have two problems.  First, your regex isn't capturing the `nds_` in the capturing group 1 that you're referencing.  Second, you are explicitly `strip`ing the `nds_` from the string even if you were to capture it.

Try:

```
m = re.match('.* (nds_[-_a-z0-9]+) ')
...
component = m.group(1)
```

Comment: @BlackVegetable...Perfect. It works beautifully. Thanks for the help.